# How to auto start VM on Ubuntu and Vmware workstation 7

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

Initially i was using window server 2008 and vmware worktation 7.
There i had .bat file and i put at startup folder to start Vms at startup.

I have chnaged my OS to ubuntu . how can i auto start VM in there

Answer (score 2):

vmrun is the correct option.  I use the following to start a VMware Workstation VM in the background.

```
vmrun start "$vmimg"  nogui
```

where $vmimg is the full path to the vmx file of the VM.  The key option that you want is the **nogui** option so that the VMware Workstation gui doesn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `vmrun` command to start up VMs in the background from the command line, and use it in `/etc/rc.local` when your system boots. (You will need to use `sudo -e /etc/rc.local` to edit that file.)

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with the details of Workstation to give you a specific example.